# How to animate movement to a text artist in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, animation

I'm trying to animate a piece of text in matplotlib, in order to make some educational videos. However, I'm having trouble with setting text in motion.

I've tried to use FuncAnimation (as I did for animating lines), and defining the anchor of that text as a pair of moving coordinates. Here's what I've tried:

```
def data_gen(): #Data generator. Gives me the anchor.
    counter = 0
    x0 = data_gen.x0
    while counter < 1000:
        counter+=1
        x0-=0.09
        yield x0,(1-counter*0.05)
data_gen.x0=1

def animate_text(data): #Here is where I try to tell my code to refresh 
#only the coordinates of the text.
    x0,y0 = data
    text_sample = ax.text(x0,y0,'text here',transform=ax.transAxes, 
fontsize=12, color='black',fontstyle='oblique',family='serif')
    return text_sample

#animation part:

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animate_text,data_gen,blit=True,
interval=50,repeat = False)
plt.show()
```

However, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 387, 
in process
proxy(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 227, 
in __call__
return mtd(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1026, in 
_start
self._init_draw()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1750, in 
_init_draw
self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1777, in 
_draw_frame
for a in self._drawn_artists:
TypeError: 'Text' object is not iterable
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 387, 
in process
proxy(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 227, 
in __call__
return mtd(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1308, in 
_handle_resize
self._init_draw()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1750, in 
_init_draw
self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1777, in 
_draw_frame
for a in self._drawn_artists:
TypeError: 'Text' object is not iterable
```

Does anybody know how can I solve that?

Comment: in documentation you can read: *" func must return an iterable of all artists that were modified or created"* . It means that `animate_text()` has to return list or tuple with elements - even if you have only one element - `return (text_sample,)`

Comment: @furas Alright! I'm editting to show the full error message

Comment: try first `return (text_sample,)` and if you get new error then add it in question with description.

Answer (score 0):

In [FuncAnimation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation) documentation you can read:

> func must return an iterable of all artists that were modified or
>   created

`"iterable"` means that `animate_text()` has to return list or tuple with elements - even if you have only one element:

```
return (text_sample,)
```